# MYSQL Count or Sum Default Value

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to use a SELECT statement to get data from MYSQL DB and store it into a DataTable.  Then I want to use the data in ASP.NET C#.  The problem is that if there is any NULL or empty data it crashes the program.  Is there anyway to set a DEFAULT value such as '0' or something when a record/cell is empty?

For example "`SELECT testID, userID, testScore FROM tableTestResults`" but sometimes testScore is null because it was never done.  Im wondering if u can set a default value for testScore whether there is a score or not.

The other example sometimes u get a null when COUNT is used, can I set a default value for that too?

Comment: Show the example query. If you don't have `GROUP BY` in it - then you don't get `NULL`, you just get an empty result (and this is different to `NULL` value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT testID, userID, IFNULL(testScore, 42) FROM tableTestResults
```

If you specifically have `NULL` there - `IFNULL` will help you

Comment: SIMPLY amazing answer, bang on and quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so like

```
SELECT testID, userID, 
case(when testScore is null then 100 else testScore end) as testScore
FROM tableTestResults
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your data table you should have an option to mark database field as 
NOT NULL, default 0

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
   ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   YearBorn YEAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

So that way you will never have null record

Answer (score 0):

You can do some simple steps to modify the data in your table and get your desire output.

```
UPDATE tableTestResults SET testScore =0
WHERE testScore isnull;
```

Then use your select statement

for future instance alter the table and set DEFAULT 0 in testScore column

Comment: It is never a good idea to **modify the original data** instead of just modifying the **output**